# Windows phone 8 & MVVM

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

Do you think I should create a ViewModel class for each View class I have or I can use a ModelView class for several View class ?

for example :

```
-ModelView
    -ItemViewModel
-View
    -ListItemView
    -AddItemView
```

In this way, I will have to instanciate twice "ItemViewModel" and I will to add in it some method usefull for only one view and other method usefull for the other one. That don't sound really great, but I'm not sure.

Comment: One view / One viewmodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly sensible to have one ViewModel for couple of Views that present slightly different aspects of the same **Model**.

A more typical approach would be to implement BaseViewModel that contains Properties and Commands common to all the 'aspects' and all the differences reflected by the derived ViewModels, ending up with one ViewModel per one View relation.